# XML getting value from specific duplicate tag using sax parser java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, desktop-application

I'm trying to getting some information in my xml using sax parser,

Here it is :

```
<IDENT>show</IDENT>
        <FORMAL_PARAM_LIST>
        FORMAL_PARAM_LIST
        </FORMAL_PARAM_LIST>
        <BLOCK_SCOPE>
        BLOCK_SCOPE
           <VAR_DECLARATION>
           VAR_DECLARATION
              <LOCAL_MODIFIER_LIST>
              LOCAL_MODIFIER_LIST
              </LOCAL_MODIFIER_LIST>
              <TYPE>
              TYPE
                 <QUALIFIED_TYPE_IDENT>
                 QUALIFIED_TYPE_IDENT
                    <IDENT>MenuUI</IDENT>
                 </QUALIFIED_TYPE_IDENT>
              </TYPE>
              <VAR_DECLARATOR_LIST>
              VAR_DECLARATOR_LIST
                 <VAR_DECLARATOR>
                 VAR_DECLARATOR
                    <IDENT>menu</IDENT>
                    <EXPR>
                    EXPR
                       <CLASS_CONSTRUCTOR_CALL>
                       STATIC_ARRAY_CREATOR
                          <QUALIFIED_TYPE_IDENT>
                          QUALIFIED_TYPE_IDENT
                             <IDENT>MenuUI</IDENT>
                          </QUALIFIED_TYPE_IDENT>
                          <ARGUMENT_LIST>
                          ARGUMENT_LIST
                          </ARGUMENT_LIST>
                       </CLASS_CONSTRUCTOR_CALL>
                    </EXPR>
                 </VAR_DECLARATOR>
              </VAR_DECLARATOR_LIST>
           </VAR_DECLARATION>
           <EXPR>
           EXPR
              <METHOD_CALL>
              METHOD_CALL
                 <DOT>.<IDENT>menu</IDENT><IDENT>showJASPform</IDENT></DOT>
                 <ARGUMENT_LIST>
                 ARGUMENT_LIST
                 </ARGUMENT_LIST>
              </METHOD_CALL>
           </EXPR>
        </BLOCK_SCOPE>
```

Basically, I want to take ident tag (), in the xml there's 4 ident, but the problem is I don't want to take them all, I only want to take the first ident (show ident) I am already trying to figure it out by implementing boolean value to flag our position in the xml's element, but I confused how I can stop at the first ident.

Thank you very much for your attention

Comment: As you've already mentioned that you are using a flag, proceed with a check in the if loop something like this: `if (identTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Ident") && Boolean.FALSE.equals(yourFlagName)) { ...}`. Initially set your flag to false,  after the first encounter with Ident tag, set it to true, that  way next time Ident tag won't be taken into consideration.

Comment: thank you for responding my ask thread, i already trying that with my approach here it is 

`if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("IDENT")){
                  
                 identFlag = true;
             } ` (in the start element) 
then   `if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("IDENT")){
                 identFlag = false;  
             } `(in the endelement)
the output are 4 ident, do i need more flag to specificly the first ident, or i do something wrong with my approach ? 

thank you very much for your time

Comment: I guess you've missed the && condition that I mentioned in my if loop, please observe that carefully. Idea basically is to set the flag to true after parsing the first occurance of <ident>, that way when next time <ident> appears the flag denies it access to the inside of the loop. I hope  that it helps, thanks :)

Comment: @robot_alien unfortunately your solution will not stop SAX parser from parsing rest of the file. It is important to stop parsing as soon as filtering goal met especially when you are paring large files.

Comment: would you be interested in an xpath based solution?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author hello sir, im open for any solution

Comment: just use xpath (//type)[1] and you are done

Comment: @vtd-xml-author yes thanks sir, but actually i already found the solution with sax ! thanks anyway sir for ur time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class derived from `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler`. Throw `SAXException` as soon as you will find desired element in `startElement()` method. This will stop SAX parser immediately.

Here are example provided - [Stop a SAX parser when you have enough data](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipsaxstop/index.html)

Comment: thank you so much for your respond, if i use this aproach (throwin saxException) that means i cant getting more information in the xml right ?  if i have to take other tag (ex. type tag) do i need to create another saxparser ?

Comment: You may create context object, which will handle parsing events and decide if criteria for parsing termination is met.

Comment: wow that clear my confusion ! thank you very much for clearing this out !

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late posting, for those u guys trying to figure this out , beside using  mr dmitry trifonov approach , u guys can use Stack method in sax , u guys can find sax's stack method article in here : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076202/java-se/mapping-xml-to-java--part-2.html

hope it helps !